# Pros and Cons of Busy Waiting on Modern Processors

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, x86, cpu-architecture

I'm using busy waiting to synchronize access to critical regions, like this:

```
while (p1_flag != T_ID);

/* begin: critical section */
for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
 ... 
}
/* end: critical section */

p1_flag++;
```

p1_flag is a global volatile variable that is updated by another concurrent thread. As a matter of fact, I've two critical sections inside a loop and I've two threads (both executing the same loop) that commute execution of these critical regions. For instance, critical regions are named A and B.

```
Thread 1     Thread 2
   A        
   B            A
   A            B
   B            A
   A            B
   B            A
                B
```

The parallel code executes faster than the serial one, however not as much as I expected. Profiling the parallel program using VTune Amplifier I noticed that a **large amount of time** is being spent in the synchronization directives, that is, the `while(...)` and flag update. I'm not sure why I'm seeing so large overhead on these "instructions" since region A is exactly the same as region B. *My best guess is that this is due the cache coherence latency: I'm using an Intel i7 Ivy Bridge Machine and this micro-architecture resolves cache coherence at the L3.* VTune also tells that the `while (...)` instruction is consuming all front-end bandwidth, but why?

To make the question(s) clear: Why are `while(...)` and update flag instructions taking so much execution time? Why would the `while(...)` instruction saturate the front-end bandwidth?

Comment: My guess is that the two threads are fighting each other for ownership of the same cache line. I'm not an expert on hardware-level synchronization, though.

Comment: There is no false-sharing between the variables. However note that there is a concurrency for the synchronization variable at the moment that both threads needs to commute regions.

Answer (score 1):

The overhead you're paying may very well be due to passing the sync variable back and forth between the core caches.

Cache coherency dictates that when you modify the cache line (p1_flag++) you need to have ownership on it. This means it would invalidate any copy existing in other cores, waiting for it to write back any changes made by that other core to a shared cache level. It would then provide the line to the requesting core in `M` state and perform the modification.

However, the other core would by then be constantly reading this line, read that would snoop the first core and ask if it has copy of that line. Since the first core is holding an `M` copy of that line, it would get written back to the shared cache and the core would lose ownership.

Now this depends on actual implementation in HW, but if the line was snooped before the change was actually made, the first core would have to attempt to get ownership on it again. In some cases i'd imagine this might take several iterations of attempts.

If you're set on using busy wait, you should at least use some pause inside it 
: `_mm_pause` intrisic, or just `__asm("pause")`. This would both serve to give the other thread a chance get the lock and release you from waiting, as well as reducing the CPU effort in busy waiting (an out-of-order CPU would fill all pipelines with parallel instances of this busy wait, consuming lots of power - a pause would serialize it so only a single iteration can run at any given time - much less consuming and with the same effect).

Comment: Hi Leeor. I totally agree with your observations! I didn't considered that the cache line could be ping-ponging between cores before being actually updated - How sure are you that this can happen? I've considered using the `pause` trick, however in the future I would like to port this program to ARM architecture - do you know if there is a similar instruction on ARM? Another thing: based on experiments I guess that the pipeline is full of loads instructions, but why doesn't the processor wait for one load to complete before issuing another one?

Comment: By the way, for x86 you can also use `cpuid` or other serializing insts. I'm not sure about ARM ISA, but there must be serializing instructions there as well. Perhaps try `ISB` (http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dai0179b/ar01s02s04.html). Keep in mind that i'm talking about instruction level serialization, not memory fencing (need to block those branches).

Comment: As for probability - this scenario is possible, not sure how probable - you could check performance counters in vtune to see how many line invalidations occur (compared to how many iterations are executed). As for `why doesn't the processor wait for one load to complete before issuing another one` - you mean across different cores? there's no mechanism for fine-grain issuing across cores, that would take so long to sync that you'd lose any benefit from parallel execution on multicore

Comment: No, I mean in the same core. In a loop like `while(p1_flag != T_ID);` seems that the processor have several in flight loads (all for the same address) how is this handled by x86? The point is, if I have several loads for the same address (in a row) will x86 wait for the first one to complete before issuing the second? I guess no.

Comment: @JohnTortugo Extensive ping-ponging for a single reader thread/single store seems unlikely for decently designed hardware. Multiple loads would occur because out-of-order can effectively unroll the while loop (using branch prediction) and stalls on data dependencies (of which there are none in the while loop, so multiple loads can be executed in parallel). ARM provides Send Event/Wait for Event (which is not scalable as any sent event will wake up all waiting threads in the system--also these are only hints). ARM's Yield allows rescheduling of hardware threads, but I do not see an ARM Pause.

Comment: @Paul: would these multiple loads (for same address) require different address in the LFB (Line Fill Buffer)?

Comment: Multiple loads issuing (and instructions in general) are part of what makes out-of-order CPUs so efficient. However, if they're to the same address they'd probably get clobbered past the memory unit, and woken up all together once the data returns. In other words - you'd get only one load at any given moment interfering with your attempts to gain ownership, but since the busy-wait is so tight - you'd always have a load like this (or the line would be in the waiting cores' cache already)

Answer (score 0):

A busy-wait is almost never a good idea in multithreaded applications.

When you busy-wait, thread scheduling algorithms will have no way of knowing that your loop is waiting on another thread, so they must allocate time as if your thread is doing useful work. And it does take processor time to check that variable over, and over, and over, and over, and over, and over...until it is finally "unlocked" by the other thread. In the meantime, your other thread will be preempted by your busy-waiting thread again and again, for no purpose at all.

This is an even worse problem if the scheduler is a priority-based one, and the busy-waiting thread is at a higher priority. In this situation, the lower-priority thread will NEVER preempt the higher-priority thread, thus you have a deadlock situation.

You should ALWAYS use semaphores or mutex objects or messaging to synchronize threads. I've never seen a situation where a busy-wait was the right solution.

When you use a semaphore or mutex, then the scheduler knows never to schedule that thread until the semaphore or mutex is released. Thus your thread will never be taking time away from threads that do real work.

Comment: I don't think this is true for all types of systems. There are scenarios where you know a wait is going to be very short (a few cycles), and the cost of putting the thread into a waiting state/waiting for the scheduler to come around is usually higher than just spinning for a few cycles.

Comment: Ben thanks for you answer. However dauphic is right. There are some cases where busy wait a few cycles is better than paying the price for a context switch. As I said in my question, A and B is the same code and I expect their execution time to be almost the same and thus I do not expected to execute the while(...) for too long.

Comment: @JohnTortugo: While I agree that dauphic is right, I'm not (at all) sure the case at hand is a good example for using a spinlock. I've used them, but typical cases were a device driver that had to wait for something like a cycle or two of a 33 MHz PCI bus.

Comment: @Jerry: If I change this sync. directives for something more "high level" the overhead is even greater. The code inside the critical regions are loops so I can unroll them to amortize the synchronization/control overhead but this didn't eliminate the problem (surely it reduces the overhead).

Comment: @JohnTortugo: Given that you seem to be just protecting a single global, then incrementing it, what I had in mind was to avoid external locks entirely, and just do an atomic increment. Since you're apparently using C++, `std::atomic<int> p1_flag;` and just `++p1_flag;` without needing any protection at all.

Comment: @Jerry: why would this be more efficient? The problem seems to be synchronization/communication overhead not atomicity..

Comment: You said you're using this to synchronize two threads. How exactly do you know it's only going to be a few cycles waiting? And how are you going to avoid a context switch for the other thread to set the variable you're waiting on?

Comment: Hi Ben. I didn't say that I knew that, I said that I expected it - because region A is equal region B. I can't avoid context switches but during profiling experiments those didn't appear to be the problem.

Comment: I have some sympathy with this answer. Pure spinlocks, (ie. with no kernel-lock fallback), have unfortunate effects when the number of ready threads exceeds the number of cores so that thread/s owning the locks can get swapped out.  Surely, the chance of this happening is low when you're only locking for long enough to push a pointer onto a queue, but this is a C++ question - a language where devs. seem to enjoy copying huge buffers by value as often as possible:(  My most vivid recollection of spinlock use was a borked cluster of eight boxes, seven deadlocked, one livelocked.

Comment: I think the data gathered so far in the question supports the idea that this particular time is NOT good time to use a spin lock. I'd be interested to see some discussion of when it WOULD be a good idea. Personally I've never seen them cause anything but trouble, unless they explicitly call Sleep() or similar inside the loop.